# ViewPager Prevent Swipe to a certain positions

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want user not to be able to swipe to certain positions in viewpager widget. Because i want them to go there by button press which i do some background work. For example for position 0 and 3, I dont want them to go there by swipe. So how can it be done?

Here is my custom view pager

```
public class SmoothViewPager  extends ViewPager{

public SmoothViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SmoothViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/* @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}*/

@Override
void smoothScrollTo(int x, int y, int velocity) {
    super.smoothScrollTo(x, y, 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the above `ViewPager` code to be as follows

```
public class SmoothViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean mAllowScroll = true;

    public SmoothViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SmoothViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mAllowScroll;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mAllowScroll;
    }

    public void setScroll(boolean allowScroll) {
        mAllowScroll = allowScroll;
    }

}
```

Here we use a boolean `mAllowScroll` to toggle the state between whether the scrolling is allowed or not. Call the `setScroll()` method from your [`OnPageChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)'s [`onPageSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)) method. Toggle the boolean based upon the page number that the user is on.

Comment: FOr some reason, in debug everything is fine but it didnt work

Comment: It also disables listview click events so it didnt work ^^

Comment: Where did `ListView` come into picture?

Comment: It was always in the picture =). Anyways with your method, i cannot reopen again because since all touch event disabled, there is no page scroll event calling occurs where i can reopen enabling again. SO once gone, always gone